# Compress array to less than 45000 bytes

Tags: arrays, sorting, math, compression, permutation

I have an partly sorted array of the elements `1...50000`. With following constraints:

1. `runs := 256`
   X elements form a Run if a[i] < a[j] and i < j
2. `inversions := 650000000`
   Two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j
3. All runs differ only 10% in length

Example:

`13648257` has 3 runs and 8 inversions

How to compress this type of array to less than 45000 bytes.

Or

How to sort this array with less than 45000 bytes sorting Information?